# Changing position of a circle when cursor is placed on it

Tags: java, position, cursor, applet, project

So i wanted to draw a circle and when the cursor is placed on top of it the circle should change its position. I got answers like when the cursor is clicked the circle will print but here the case is the circle has to change to its position to another place. can someone help me with this.

Comment: 1) [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 4) Applets have become completely unworkable for sites dealing to 'all comers' on the internet.  ..

Comment: .. Safari and FF both block applets by default, and Chrome and IE are set to completely remove support for them.  It is best to transition away from applets to pure JS/HTML sooner rather than later.